# How to push React with .Net core application to heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I have completed making one application using react in front end and .net core at backend. Now I need to publish this repository to heruko. Locally, when I do dotnet build and run it it works fine but while pushing it to heroku i am getting an error

> :   /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmp35fd435a650b4b94a93ab28064f9c447.exec.cmd: npm: not found
> remote: /tmp/build_46ea6d26/API/API.csproj(50,3): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app.
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push failed
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to librarymanagementsysteminsight.
> remote:
> To https://git.heroku.com/librarymanagementsysteminsight.git
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/librarymanagementsysteminsight.git'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Provide Heroku relevant files (.net core and node.js dependencies, Procfile and so on). You also get more information when you deploy an app from the Heroku website. It will have a build log. Provide that log.  
Your current log only says that the git push was rejected due to an error in the building step.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a checklist respectively,

- Check ASP.NET CORE compiled version
- Check ASP.NET CORE runtime version
- Check you npm version
- Check your folder that base of your heroku app, specify it according to language. You do not run npm in your ASP.CORE folder
- Check permissions of your git repo

Also, you are trying to push your code into master.
It is not recommended. Create Branch and use it to push.

Comment: "Note that Heroku only deploys code that you push to master or main. Pushing code to another branch of the heroku remote has no effect." He has to push to master. He can have locally a different branch but he will still need to commit to master `git push heroku testbranch:master` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

Comment: hmm, I didn't know this info. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 buildpacks:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Asp.net core with react demo app deployed to Heroku https://github.com/jincod/AspNetCoreDemoApp